# c# task acting on later reference

Tags: c#, reference, task

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
{
  Task task = new Task(() => DoWork(list[i]));
  task.Start();
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can ensure that the `DoWork` function will act on the list at the position `i`?

I am having an issue where the task will start at some point after the next iteration of the `for` loop so I get duplicate threads essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the *variable* is captured by the lambda expression, and you're then modifying it. There are a few simple options:

First, copying the variable to a variable which is *instantiated* within the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    int copy = i;
    Task task = new Task(() => DoWork(list[copy]));
    task.Start();
}
```

Now each iteration will capture a different `copy` variable, which isn't modified elsewhere.

Second, introducing a local variable but with `list[i]` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var item = list[i];
    Task task = new Task(() => DoWork(item));
    task.Start();
}
```

Third, and *only* if you're using C# 5 or later, using `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Task task = new Task(() => DoWork(item));
    task.Start();
}
```

In earlier versions of C# that would have the same problem as your original code, as a single `item` variable would change in each iteration. From C# 5 onwards, each iteration of the `foreach` loop introduces a new iteration variable.

As a side note, from .NET 4.5 onwards it's typically simpler to use `Task.Run` instead of creating a new task and then starting it.